# Script to monitor cpu time for each process for multiple Windows systems

Tags: powershell, process, cpu-time

I'm trying to monitor the CPU time for all processes running on multiple computers in order to track down which process could be taxing the CPU at specific times. I'd like to be able to collect the usage and export it to a csv for further review. Here's what I have so far but it only works for a single system. Thanks!

Script:

```
while ($true) {
  Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples| Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 10| ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}} -AutoSize 
}
```

I have tried the code above but it is limited to one system and I am unable to export the results for further review.

Comment: What do you mean it's limited to one system? How? As far as exporting, are you receiving an error?

Comment: Hi, it was limited in the sense that I couldn't get the right syntax to query multiple servers but I ended up fixing my loop statement and that piece works now. However, If I try exporting the results I don't get the right output. I get this value "#TYPE System.String for the first row and column. 
"

Comment: $Servers = (Get-Content "C:\Temp\Servers.txt")

foreach ($Server in $Servers) { 

Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples| Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| ? {$_.instanceName -notmatch "^(idle|_total|system)$"} | Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 10| ft InstanceName,@{L='CPU';E={($_.Cookedvalue/100/$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS).toString('P')}} -AutoSize 

} Export-Csv "C:\Temp\cpu_time.csv"

Comment: you're missing a pipe before your export, and the extra value is produced when you don't specify `-NoTypeInformation`. Try to not post code in the comments either, it's hard to read.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have added the info you suggested and although the csv file is created, it is empty and does not include any of the values the script is producing.

Comment: if you can update your post on how you're running it, I maybe can help a bit better.